# Removing several select options from list

Tags: jquery

Code reads value from database, and depending on it I want it to remove options from select list. I've managed to do this using jQuery function filter().remove to remove unnecessary options but I don't know how to remove arbitrary options, and not like this. For example how to remove 2,3,4,5 option?  Select looks like this:

```
<select name="year">
<option value="1">First</option>
<option value="2">Second</option>
<option value="3">Third</option>
<option value="4">Fourth</option>
<option value="5">Fifth</option>
<option value="6">Sixth</option>
</select>
```

And code for removing options:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('[name=year] option').filter(function(){
return parseInt(this.value) <4 
}).remove();    });
```

This code removes every options with value below 4. Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use your original method and just build an array of the values to remove like this:

```
var ary = [2,3,4,5];
$('[name=year] option').filter(function () {
    return ($.inArray(parseInt(this.value),ary) > -1);
}).remove();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vpV3q/2/)**

Comment: tnx a lot for fast help :)